# Why are utmp, wtmp and btmp called as they are?

Tags: logs, history

I know what these files record, but I'd like to known what 'u','w','b' prefixes mean.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 19):

The 'u' stands for user. `utmp` gives information about who is on the system.
The 'w' in `wtmp` probably comes from 'who'.
The 'b' comes from 'bad', `btmp` records the bad login attempts.

The names are a bit cryptic, as so often on Unix/Linux.

Comment: And the tmp part is for 'temp'? I'm seriously asking.

Comment: No idea, I searched a bit but could not find anything. `utmp` of course has fleeting, temporary, information and was the initial file available, but I have no confirmation that that might be the origin of that name part. You should post that as a new question.

Comment: Does it possible `'w'` come from `'when'`? Because `wtmp` records **when** user logged in and logged out.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good [summary of their usage](https://bromiley.medium.com/torvalds-tuesday-logon-history-in-the-tmp-files-83530b2acc28) by Linus Torvalds but it doesn't go much into the history.

The names `utmp` and `wtmp` go all the way back to earliest days of UNIX in the 1970's.

Both files existed in UNIX v6, where the [`ac`](https://github.com/memnoth/unix-v6/blob/master/source/s2/who.c) and [`who`](https://github.com/memnoth/unix-v6/blob/master/source/s2/who.c) commands would report on their contents. (Curiously the `who` command would report ["cannot open *wtmp*"](https://github.com/memnoth/unix-v6/blob/master/source/s2/who.c#L27) if `/etc/utmp` was unreadable.)

Initially `utmp` was in `/etc` and `wtmp` was in `/usr/adm/wtmp`.

Both files were moved under `/var` when that was split from `/usr` in the 1980's, at first into `/var/adm` and later into `/var/log`.

To be sure why those names were chosen you'd have to ask Ken Thompson, or search through Dennis Richie's archive.

I suspect that `/etc/utmp` was created first and the others names were based on it. Being in `/etc` where everything else was static may have contributed to using `tmp` for a file that was created anew each time the system is booted. Or perhaps it was a temporary idea that caught on, and kept its quixotic filename.

`btmp` was added much later; I don't think it existed when I started using Linux in 1994.

Obviously `u` refers to "user" and `b` simply indicates "bad" (failed) logins, but `w` is less clear. If I had to guess (and knowing the tendency for puns and linguistic quirks) `wtmp` could be from `uutmp` ("user usage") being read as "double U temp".