# utmp, wtmp and btmp: what is the 'tmp'

Tags: history, last, wtmp, btmp

From the earlier question:

[why are utmp, wtmp and btmp called as they are?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127211/why-are-utmp-wtmp-and-btmp-called-as-they-are)

I would like to now what the 'tmp' part is. Is it 'temp/temporary'. As you can see from the earlier question, that part wasn't answered.

Answer (score 7):

`tmp` may be short for *temporary* (as in *transient*) since these files are, like log files, periodically rotated/truncated.  The `utmp` and `wtmp` files also initially resided in `/tmp` when they were introduced [in Version 3 AT&T Unix](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V3-Snapshot-Development/man/man5/utmp.5).

However,  `tmp` could nowadays be read as an abbreviation of *timestamp*. `tm` is also a common abbreviation of *time* (see, e.g., the manual for the `ctime()` C function and [the `time.h` header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html)) and these files contain the timestamps for system events relating to users logging in.

- The `u` in `utmp` likely comes from *user*.
- The `b` in `btmp` (on systems that has it) likely comes from *bad* (bad logins).
- The `w` in `wtmp` *may* come from *who* (as in "who was logged in?"), but not from `who` or `w` (the utilities) as they use `utmp` and not `wtmp`.

Comment: I suspect this is incorrect. If you look at the actual C implementation of the `utmp` stuff, you'll see a lot of the struct members contain `ut_...`, indicating that the `ut` is the prefix, and separate from the `mp` part. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html

Comment: @Patrick I know. The other explanation for the `ut_` struct members is that `ut` is the first two characters of `utmp`, and nothing more than that.

Comment: To pick a nit: utmp existed in V1 already. See http://a.papnet.eu/UNIX/v1man/man5/utmp, datestamped November 1971. It did reside in /tmp, though later man pages locate it in /etc.